# Drawing a sketchy-looking line, programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4, uikit

I would like to know if you guys have any idea of how I could possibly draw a sketchy-looking line on an iOS app.
Currently I am drawing thanks to a UIBezierPath which I then render into a bitmap graphics context. How could I make the line look sketchy?

```
// Produce and add points to draw in the UIBezierPath

// Draw the path into the Bitmap context

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);  
        [frameBuffer drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0) blendMode:kCGBlendModeCopy alpha:1.0];
        [[datasource lineStrokeColorForSketchCanvas:self] setStroke];
        [curvePath stroke];    
image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Thank ou very much in advance :)

Comment: Do you have an example of what you mean by "sketchy"?

Comment: edit because of wrong link. Don't know how to delete it

Comment: Not this exactly, but something similar [link]http://www.boxesandarrows.com/files/banda/sketchy-wireframes/4_Travis_Search_Line_Conversion.gif

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a small batch of "sketchy" line textures, and then using those + the UIBezierPath to place the sketchy images along the path at the correct rotation.

You could draw those to the context, and save them so that you don't have to generate them every single time.

Elaboration:

Start at one end of your UIBezierPath, every x points down the path, draw a sketchy line section centered on that point, keep going until you get to the end of the path.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that a bit more? I don't really understand what you mean.

Comment: The way I create the UIBezierPath is through the touchesMoved and so on, so I can do some computing on every new line of the Bezier path and so on. What I still don't know or understand is how I can draw that sketchy line section centered on those points. Should I use some kind of pre made bitmap image and render it there, or how can I do it?Thanks!

Comment: You'll be drawing bitmap "stamps" of sketchy lines along the path to the context.