# How to draw line like Chalk drawing stroke in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, drawing, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

I want to draw line, like chalk. And the line's edge is faint. Just like use chalk draw on blackboard.

How do I get this? Now, I had drawed line using image, but it doesn't look like draw on blackboard, because the line is not faint. Please, give me some suggestions.

My Code in `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` Method:

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
[curImage  drawInRect:self.bounds];
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
 [self.layer renderInContext:context];

  UIImage *imgType = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:self.strFile ofType:@"png"]];
 [imgType drawInRect:CGRectMake(currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y, 40, 40)];

 curImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 [curImage retain];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

[image: Output]

[image: Chalk Pattern Image]

Comment: Use OpenGL ES  to draw this. First draw a texture like this and draw a line using this tecture

Comment: I tried with that, but I can not get smooth drawing

Comment: Can you pls give example

Comment: If you want to try with cocos2d, have a look at this. http://www.merowing.info/2012/04/drawing-smooth-lines-with-cocos2d-ios-inspired-by-paper/ . I also asked a similar question a while ago and this is the responses I got. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864276/drawing-a-sketchy-looking-line-programmatically